# mod rewrite problem with 2 parameters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, pagination

I'm trying to rewrite the categoy file of my shop system, I also integrated a pagination so I need to rewrite 2 parameters. it almost works, otherwise I wouldn't be posting in here

this is the rewriteurl

```
RewriteRule ^shop/cat/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)$ /cmstut/shop/cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This is the url

```
http://localhost/cmstut/shop/cat/32/page/2
```

the cat works but not the page and when I print the querystring I get this:

```
cat=32/page/2
```

What did I do wrong? I was expecting something like cat=32&page=2 so I could catch the page and show the right page for the pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably having two rules where the second one looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/cat/(.*)$ /cmstut/shop/cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rule will cause that a request of `shop/cat/32/page/2` will be rewritten wrong. You need to use a more specific pattern like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/cat/([^/]+)$ shop/cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/cat/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ shop/cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: yes exactly, thanks a lot I thought I was editing the first line but I've added a new one... no idea what I was thinking :D

I had the same problem with another page where I have the same problem so that's also fixed :D thanks a lot